# infinity scroll scraping: getting only first 40 data where it contains 440 data. with selenium and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hello there I am trying to scrap a webpage if i scroll down to last it showing 440 items but if i scrap with below code it only returning first 40. Please help:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import json
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Set up the web driver (make sure to have the appropriate driver for your browser installed)
path_to_driver = Service(executable_path=r'D:/Projects/web_scraping/Chrome_driver/chromedriver.exe')  # Replace with the path to your ChromeDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=path_to_driver)

url = "https://www.airbnb.com/?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&search_mode=flex_destinations_search&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=one_week&location_search=MIN_MAP_BOUNDS&monthly_start_date=2023-09-01&monthly_length=3&price_filter_input_type=0&price_filter_num_nights=5&channel=EXPLORE&search_type=category_change&category_tag=Tag%3A8678"
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

elements = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'body')
def scroll_to_end():
    while True:       wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'dir-ltr')))
        elements.send_keys(Keys.END)
        time.sleep(4)
        if driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight - window.scrollY <= window.innerHeight"):
            break
scroll_to_end()
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
data = soup.select_one('#data-deferred-state')   #data-state
data = json.loads(data.text)
items =  data["niobeMinimalClientData"][0][1]["data"]["presentation"]["explore"]["sections"]["sectionIndependentData"]["staysMapSearch"]["mapSearchResults"]

for item in items:
    item_id = item['listing']['id']
    print(item_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All data not coming into the json format. So i get the data after rendered.

```
elements = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'body')

def scroll_to_end():
    while True:       wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'dir-ltr')))
        elements.send_keys(Keys.END)
        time.sleep(4)
        if driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight - window.scrollY <= window.innerHeight"):
            break

scroll_to_end()

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
data = soup.select_one('#site-content')
item_list_elements = data.find_all(attrs={'itemprop': 'itemListElement'})
urls = [element.find('meta', itemprop='url')['content'] for element in item_list_elements]
```

And it extract all the items i needed.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it's a bit tricky as far as new items are rendered async, so you need to implement continuous scroll that checks that new items are appeared and rendered.
In such cases it's better to use official API, than rely on frontend.

Anyway, this is basic solution. It's not ideal and not quick, but it works and you need  to optimize it if you want.

```py
def scrollToEnd():
    while True:
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class*=dir-ltr] [itemprop=itemListElement]')))
        last_height = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset")
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 500)", "")
        driver.execute_script(
            "const waitForCollectionLengthChange=(collection,timeout)=>new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{const initialLength=collection().length;const checkLengthChange=()=>{if(collection().length!==initialLength){resolve(collection())}else{const currentTime=new Date().getTime();if(currentTime-startTime>=timeout){resolve(collection())}else{setTimeout(checkLengthChange,1000)}}};const startTime=new Date().getTime();checkLengthChange();});const elementsGetter=()=>document.querySelectorAll('[class*=dir-ltr] [itemprop=itemListElement]');await waitForCollectionLengthChange(elementsGetter,5000);")
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break

scrollToEnd()
```

Js function that waits for elements collection length to be changed (more readable)

```js
function waitForCollectionLengthChange(collection, timeout) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const initialLength = collection().length;

    const checkLengthChange = () => {
      if (collection().length !== initialLength) {
        resolve(collection());
      } else {
        const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        if (currentTime - startTime >= timeout) {
            resolve(collection()) // we don't need reject there in particular case
        } else {
          setTimeout(checkLengthChange, 1000);
        }
      }
    };

    const startTime = new Date().getTime();
    checkLengthChange();
  });
}

const elementsGetter = () => document.querySelectorAll("[class*=dir-ltr] [itemprop=itemListElement]")

await waitForCollectionLengthChange(elementsGetter, 5000);
```

Comment: Still not working..

Comment: How many results do you get with my code?  Try to chage scrollBy Y from 500 to 300

Comment: From my code i am getting only 40 results. I cannot use your code as i can't use js. Please help

Comment: Just copy paste first snippet and tell me if it works (it should)

Comment: showing error at 

```function waitForCollectionLengthChange(collection, timeout)```